# Compiling text into angular html for a specific scope and render it into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have some specific requirement. I have html pages for a functionality (like popup). I want that html to be rendered while changing my state. In this, my state specific HTML is different. Html which I want to render is should get render as a immediate child of body and it contains Angular tag like ng-click etc.

I want to load it by calling a function(manually).

This worked for me :

```
$http.get("/myTemplate.html").then(function(response) {
    var raw_html = response.data;

    $('body').append($compile(raw_html)(myScope));
});
```

But as per security concern, I can't use $('body').append (jquery apppend)

So I tried it from pure javascript :

```
$http.get("/myTemplate.html").then(function(response) {
    var raw_html = response.data;
    var element = document.createElement("div"); 
    element.className = 'myClass';
    element.innerHTML = raw_html;
    document.body.appendChild($compile(element)(currentScope));
});
```

But what $compile return is not compatible with appendChild.

Can directive help me in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ng-include.

You can use it in 3 different ways:

```
<div ng-include="'/myTemplate.html'"></div>
<div ng-include src='/myTemplate.html'"></div>
<ng-include src="'/myTemplate.html'">
```

If you must go the other way, you can refer to the dom object by element[0]

#### Edited

```
document.body.appendChild($compile(element)(currentScope)[0]);
```

Comment: Because, I want that template at immediate child of body, not under ng-view to override z-index of header and all.

Comment: No it is not working because appendChild not accepting $compile(element[0])(currentScope) as argument but $('body').append do.

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this document.body.appendChild($compile(element)(currentScope)[0]);

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use jQuery, use [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to wrap the *body* in angular's jqLite instead.

```
angular.element(document.body).append($compile(raw_html)(myScope));
```